# Rendering xml file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my xml code in Android Studio. I am facing Rendering Problem in my Xml File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.myapp1.MainActivity1"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Manab"
        android:id="@+id/M_shaw"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:text="45645" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Person1"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Person2"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:checked="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

error shown is-:
Exception raised  during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class 
and also the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
Help resolve this problem.

Comment: Does com.example.admin.myapp1.MainActivity1 exist?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve]. You need to show the full logcat in order for us to help

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have problem related to the Gradle cache.
**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13123395)

Comment: The essentials are here "Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart" is the menu buttons in android studio - additonal link for more information